# How to create icons from multiple image files fast (in the typed code)?

Tags: java, image, swing, import

I have over 100 images I need to associate to newly created `ImageIcon` objects. How can I import them faster than manually typing this for each image?

```
ImageIcon imagefile = new ImageIcon("imagefile")
```

I'm coding in Eclipse.

Comment: One way is to create an ant/maven/whatever task that makes and includes a list of the images in the Jar.  Voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: What do you know about arrays and/or collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you could write some code to write code for you (if thats what you need to do. )

Then once the code has been output you can copy/paste it into the class in your application.

For example something like this would save you a lot of typing:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CodeWritingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String rootFolder = "src/res/"; // or args[0]
        File folder = new File(rootFolder);
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("png") ||     file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("jpg")) {
                printFilename(file, "src/".length());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printFilename(File file, int stripIndex) {
        String variableName = file.getName().replaceAll("[.]", "_");
        String template = "ImageIcon " + variableName + " = new ImageIcon(\"" + file.getPath().substring(stripIndex) + "\")";
        System.out.println(template);
    }
}
```

If you desire you could modify the System.out.println in the printFilename method to automatically write code to do something such as add these items to a list or a hashmap.

Comment: pretty sure the question is asking how he can save on typing out a single line 100 times,..

My suggestion was to pretty much have him write a method that autogenerated that code for him.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have elaborated my code as to help you see my approach, 

I should point out that when I wrote my original response I did not see any comments posted.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have cleaned up the post a little (with clearer instructions) and other minor edits. I have also removed my noisy comments also.

Comment: See also [`ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getReaderFileSuffixes--) & [`File.listFiles(FileFilter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FileFilter-).